# What are the two ways I can write this statement with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I understand that there are two different ways I can write LINQ code. Can someone show me the two ways for this simple code block. Which is the most commonly used or considered most easy to debug

```
    var subTopics = _subTopicService.GetSubTopics(Id);
    var subTopicsSelect = (from subTopic in subTopics
          select new
          {
              id = subTopic.SubTopicId,
              name = subTopic.Name
          });
```

Comment: this question sounds very familiar to me, I've read this somewhere in stackoverflow?

Comment: 1 way is using `Query expression`, another is using `Query method`, however `Query method` can solve most of your work while `Query expression` is just for convenient in some simple cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query consists solely of a `from` and `select` clause, all you need to do to convert this to fluent syntax is call [`.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

In fluent syntax, that would be:

```
var subTopicsSelect = subTopics.Select(x => 
     new 
     {
          id = x.SubTopicId, 
          name = x.Name 
     });
```

**Further Reading**

- [How to: Write LINQ Queries in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have displayed the first way "SQL-like syntax" the second would be "Lambda syntax":

```
subTopics.Select(s => new { id = s.SubTopicId, name = s.Name });
```

Answer (score 0):

This really confuses me as I have a completely different way to select here are the two methods:

```
    var emailsToSend = db.emailQueues.Where(
            e => e.sent == false
        ).Take(5);


    var emailsToSend2 = from e2 in db.emailQueues
                            .Take(5)
                            .Where(
                            e => e.sent == false
                        ) 

                        select e2;
```

They both seem to do exactly the same thing but i prefer the syntax of the first method. Its easier to remember.

Comment: They don't do the same as you swapped the order of Take and Where. If you take that into account your second version is just the famous `from x in source select x` which can be replaces by `source`.